# Adicionar hiperligação em <a onclick

Tags: html, jquery, css

A página é esta

Os menus estão feitos com anchors e eu queria adicionar um link a redirecionar para uma pagina externa exatamente no mesmo sitio.
Já tentei adicionar um  mas sem sucesso, tenho conhecimentos de html/css/php mas não estou a conseguir fazer o que pretendo.
Quando eu digo sem sucesso, quero dizer que a hiperligação não funciona, e ao adicionar o meu código no meio dos outros menus o texto vai para o topo da página no front end.

Espero que alguem me consiga ajudar.
Obrigado,
Daniel

o código é o seguinte e o objetivo é adicinar um link com uma hiperligação para uma pagina externa, mas que esta posicionada no mesmo sitio com o mesmo estilo que esses menus.
(Tentei fazer eu próprio o que está a bold)

```
<header id="menu" class="menu">
  <div class="posScroll"></div>
  <div class="main">    
    <a onclick="$('#area0').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="logo" class="logo"></a>
    <a onclick="$('#area1').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav1" class="itemMenu">
      ECOPAINT
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area2').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav2" class="itemMenu">
      GO GREEN
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area3').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav3" class="itemMenu">
      Shёrbime
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area4').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav4" class="itemMenu">
      Materiale Eco
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area5').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav5" class="itemMenu">
      Çmime
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area6').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav6" class="itemMenu">
      Rreth botёs
    </a>
    <a onclick="$('#area7').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="nav7" class="itemMenu">
      Përshëndetje
    </a>
    **<a onclick="window.location.href=''" id="nav8" class="itemMenu">ONLINE STORE</a>**
    <div class="headerContact">
    Ecopaint Albania<br>
    <a href="mailto:"></a><br>
    +351 229 826 029   
    </div>
    <button id="showRight"></button>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta e explique melhor o que quer fazer e o problema.

Comment: @Sam Obrigado :)

Comment: Não consegui perceber o que pretendes fazer. Você quer que um desses links, ao ser clicado, vá para outra página?

Comment: @Sam Sim, isso já consegui. O que eu quero é que no Chrome o link "Online Store" apareça no mesmo sitio que no Firefox. Estou tambem a tentar mudar a cor do link depois de clicado mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel

Seu click não está funcionando porquê a tag do seu logotipo está em cima do link que criou. Comente ou remova a linha abaixo e faça um teste, será possível clicar no link:

```
<a onclick="$('#area0').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1000,easing:'easeOutQuint'});" id="logo" class="logo"></a>
```

Reorganize o HTML de sua página para que não ocorra essa sobreposição de elementos.

Além disso você não precisa usar onClick para fazer um redirecionamento entre páginas, para isso você pode usar o padrão da tag anchor com o href. Da uma olhada em:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

A respeito da sobreposição de elementos, caso tenha dúvida dê uma olhada nesses links:

https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-usar-a-propriedade-position-css/24451
https://www.devmedia.com.br/css-z-index-entendendo-sobre-o-eixo-z-na-web/28698

Comment: No firefox funciona, mas no chrome não. O "link" fica posicionado no topo da janela. No Firefox está correto, com o CSS que coloquei ele está ao lado dos outros links.

Comment: Hoje em dia é raro haver incompatibilidade entre navegadores, eu mesmo nem me dou o trabalho mais de testar entre os navegadores, geralmente o problema é o HTML/CSS que foi escrito. Uma sugestão que tenho pra ti é evitar de ficar posicionando manualmente cada menu com o position:absolute e left, há 1001 jeitos mais simples de fazer isso. Exemplo -> https://jsfiddle.net/ricardomalias/u6oe9yks/9/ ... Você também pode usar bibliotecas como bootstrap, facilitará tua vida -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/product/

Comment: Ricardo obrigado, mas o meu conhecimento não é assim tão avançado.

Comment: Mas vai tentando Daniel, ninguém nasce sabendo

Comment: estou a tentar mas sem sucesso. Consegui realmente adicionar o link, mas no chrome o link Online Store está no topo da página totalmente desajustado.